# Is there an alternative to DbFunctions for PostgreSQL?

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

Is there an alternative to `DbFunctions` (like `DbFunctions.TruncateTime`, `DbFunctions.DiffDays`, etc.) for PostgreSQL?

So far I have tried `NpgsqlDbFunctionsExtensions`. But it's not exactly what I need and it does not provide all the features I need. I would like to have something as close as possible to `DbFunctions`.

Comment: `DbFunctions` is the db-agnostic API implemented by specific database providers like `NpgsqlDbFunctionsExtensions` or `MySqlDbFunctionsExtensions`. What features are you looking for? `does not provide all the features I need` is unclear. The features you want may be implemented somewhere else or you may have to map the functions yourself

Comment: The provider (Npgsql in your case) is the one translating the methods you call into database constructs. You can't just mix & match those. What functions in particular do you need? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping for creating mappings yourself.

Comment: EF Core allows you to [map custom methods to database functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/user-defined-function-mapping).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's EF6 I use.

Comment: @CodeCaster It's EF6 I use.

Comment: That doesn't change what I said, it just requires a different link to documentation.

Comment: EF 6 also allowed function mapping. `EntityFramework6.Npgsql` is 2 years old though, and EF 6 itself is 10 years old. Finding the docs requires a "bit" of digging. What features are you looking for? Perhaps they were implemented in EF Core.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ideally - everything that `DbFunctions` has) or something of maximum intersection, or several thing that together cover it all.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Migration to EF Core hasn't been approved yet by the management.

Comment: What features are you looking for? They be mapped in a different way. For example, the [NpgSqlTextFunctions](https://github.com/npgsql/EntityFramework6.Npgsql/blob/main/EF6.PG/NpgsqlTextFunctions.cs) class maps functions like `to_tsvector` that don't exist in EF 6's DbFunctions. You could use the `DbFunction` attribute as a starting point to create your own mappings. You may have to [register a custom convention](https://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/registering-sql-server-built-in-functions-to-entity-framework-code-first) to map the name and parameters though

Comment: As for `hasn't been approved yet by the management` there's a cost and a risk associated with using a 10-year-old technology. I used custom mappings too, but no longer remember how it was done except that it required some tricks. Back then all code was in Codeplex which no longer exists. Any tools I used are probably gone. Searching/Googling returns hits mainly for EF Core, even for `DbFunctionAttribute`